# Anything button related on KivyMd doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, macos, kivy, kivymd

Im using: MacOS Big Sur, KivyMd version - v0.104.2.dev (I tried using the stable release and it still doesn't solve the problem), and python version 3.9.4.

Nothing related to KivyMD buttons (MDFlatButton, MDFilledRoundFlatIconButton, MDRaisedButton, etc) work, except the MDIconButton.

When I run any code with a KivyMD button in it, it gives me this error(even when I try clicking on the button option in kitchen sink the window closes and gives me the following error in the terminal):

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/chaithanya/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-05-10_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0.dev0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.4 (v3.9.4:1f2e3088f3, Apr  4 2021, 12:32:44) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-16.1.12'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel Iris OpenGL Engine'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2.dev0, git-8f83652, 2021-05-10 (installed at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: sdl2(['clipboard_nspaste'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 702, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 555, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1264, in kivy.properties.BoundedNumericProperty.check
 TypeError: Cannot convert kivy.properties.NumericPropertyStorage to kivy.properties.BoundedNumericPropertyStorage
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/chaithanya/KivyMD/demos/kitchen_sink/main.py", line 144, in <module>
     KitchenSinkApp().run()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 580, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 345, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 389, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 340, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 306, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 719, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/list.py", line 854, in on_touch_up
     super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/ripple_behavior.py", line 296, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 719, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Users/chaithanya/KivyMD/demos/kitchen_sink/main.py", line 86, in <lambda>
     "on_release": lambda x=name_item_example: self.set_example_screen(
   File "/Users/chaithanya/KivyMD/demos/kitchen_sink/main.py", line 108, in set_example_screen
     screen_object = eval(self.data_screens[name_screen]["Factory"])
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 274, in __init__
     super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/backgroundcolor_behavior.py", line 189, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/backgroundcolor_behavior.py", line 147, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwarg)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/elevation.py", line 847, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 359, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 542, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 664, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 664, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 664, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
     child.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 542, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 711, in _apply_rule
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 16:
 ...
      14:    size_hint: None, None
      15:    height: dp(20) + lbl_txt.texture_size[1]
 >>   16:    width: lbl_txt.texture_size[0] + dp(24)
      17:
      18:    MDLabel:
 ...
 TypeError: Cannot convert kivy.properties.NumericPropertyStorage to kivy.properties.BoundedNumericPropertyStorage
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 702, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 555, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1264, in kivy.properties.BoundedNumericProperty.check
```

Here is the code I'm running, everything works fine until I add the button:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
##from kivy.core.window import Window
##Window.size = (280, 500)

login = '''
FloatLayout:
    MDLabel:
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.9,'center_y':.85}
        text:'LOGIN'
        font_size:80
    MDTextField:
        id:user
        hint_text:'Username'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.75}
        size_hint:.5,.1
    MDTextField:
        id:passw
        hint_text:'Password'
        password:True
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.65}
        size_hint:.5,.1
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text:'Login'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.55}
        size_hint:.2,.1
    
'''

class LoginApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(login)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Kivy and KivyMD and installed the stable releases for both,now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to return a string please use f'{}' to solve the problem.
it is so easy.
best

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).